# 'Set' or 'Map' is undefined in IE9 ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-9

I have created a simple application with react 16.2.0 and when I execute/run it on IE9 it shows me console error 'Set' or 'Map' is undefined.

Comment: Check the supported browsers for Set here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set, IE9 is not one of them,

Comment: Have you read the official docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that there are some polyfills require to run my react application on IE9. I followed following steps and it worked for me. As React 16 depends on the collection types Map and Set. If you support older browsers and devices which may not yet provide these natively (e.g. IE < 11), consider including a global polyfill in your bundled application, such as core-js or babel-polyfill.

We also have to use requestAnimationFrame polyfill library which is **raf**

`npm install --save raf`

**index.js**

```
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'raf/polyfill';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to find and add pollyfills for set and map as well if it's not working.